# Opening multiple calculators with a single batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

So i essentially need to create a batch file, that opens multiple windows of an application, example a calculator here. My actual project is to make it open over a few thousand times, so that the system crashes. I've looked over for loops and learnt a little batch scripting syntax and etc. But i don't really know much, and concluded on a block of code to open a trail bat file to open 20 calculators, multiple environments without the first one exiting.

```
    @echo off
    set count=0
    :loop
    set /a count=%count%+1
    start /MIN /DC:\Windows\System32 calc.exe
    if %count% neq 20 goto loop
```

But i don't understand, the behavior is erratic. Sometimes, my system crashes. I've tried using the "for" syntax as well

```
    @echo off
    for /L %%a IN (1,1,20) DO start "" "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
```

And this one crashes my system or opens only a single calculator, which might mean that the previous instances are closing and only the last one opens.

So how do i modify my code?.. or perhaps is there a better script in batch files to open multiple environments of an application?

Comment: What happens if you try to execute it multiple times from _cmd_?

Comment: The "for" command on cmd works perfectly fine, i checked it right now.

Comment: Are you sure it is only opening a single calculator? If you get it to open this many at once, it might lag and take several seconds to open the others. Also it will compress them in your taskbar as a single item

Comment: Again, it's unpredictable this time. On cmd, it opens either single, or five or four- sometimes, all of them close automatically. 

Of course, when i first ran it (the "for" command) , it was fine, opening a bunch of them. But now it's acting up on it's own. The batch file opens one first.. and when i run it again, it opens 16 calculators.. it's being messy @Monacraft

Comment: If your real goal is to crash the system, why cap yourself? Why not just make it run indefinitely?

Comment: @Monacraft  That actually worked right now, my laptop crashed just when i set the value to 1000. Thanks~ 

But i was just curious as to how to write a correct script for multiple instances.

Comment: Try using it for notepad and see if that works with your current code (the `for /l` loop) AFAIK your current code looks fine

Comment: Why do you think it would crash? What happens is it is unable to create new stuff (processes/windows) till an an existing one is closed. And there may not be enough free memory to create a messagebox window to tell you. Also every program opened adds to virtual memory.

Comment: Also Calculator is always ONE PROCESS no matter how many windows are open. So that's a bad choice as each window uses little memory compared to a process.

Comment: @ACatInLove Thanks for the explanation. I've almost guessed that and it's clear now.

Comment: Also the same process uses the same physical memory with only data different. You need to open different programs.